# time zone conversion issue using shopify liquid template

Tags: datetime, timezone, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am dealing with some date information from a JSON. I'm using Shopify's liquid template to traverse thru the JSON and extract the date time entry value. 
Here is the sample input i have:

```
{
    "BookSet" :
    {
        "CreatedDate" : "2019-04-25T12:30:00+01:00",
        "Price": "$20",
        "Title": "Basic Tech"
    }
}
```

And the liquid commands we have developed is:

```
<set-body template="liquid">{
{% assign responsePayload = body.BookSet %}
"Data": 
{
    "Publish_Date":"{{responsePayload.CreatedDate}}"
}
</set-body>
```

The output we are receiving is:

```
{
    "Data": 
    {
        "Publish_Date":"4/25/2019 11:30:00 AM"
    }
}
```

But we don't want the date time value to be adjusted to GMT timezone here.
our expected output should be:

```
{
    "Data": 
    {
        "Publish_Date":"2019-04-25T12:30:00+01:00"
    }
}
```

We have tried to convert this date value to string using capture function,  but that is also not functioning as expected.

Comment: Hi.  Please edit your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my question. Included samples as input, code and outputs.

Comment: Well, you're not passing a ` | date` filter, so if the input is a string then it should just come out as a string as you are asking for.  Is there somewhere else where you parse the JSON and are turning the string into an object?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, the question is more about (1) how to keep the original datetime format and (2) why by default the liquid template makes any conversion at all?